# Examples of healthy lifelong asymptomatic carrier of a severe infectious disease?

Tags: evolution, infectious-diseases

I am curious, is there any known disease/infection that is very severe normally (patient suffers greatly and die easily without medical treatment), but ends up having little to no effect on the lives of asymptomatic carriers? I am asking this as I am thinking whether this means certain disease symptoms are mechanisms resulted from evolution to protect the "greater good", i.e. killing the patient to avoid transmission to another member of the species.

Comment: I think this question is probably strongly misguided. For now I've given it a downvote; better research and focus might encourage me to change my mind on that. But as-is, it seems too contaminated with misunderstanding of both evolution and disease.

Comment: Research needed aside, in what way it is misguided? Isnt it just asking for a possibility (a possible example and possible reason behind)? And I am not quite sure I like the way you are judging it by "probably" and "seem", without giving any actual reason.

Comment: @ychung What I meant is that there are underlying assumptions, not contained in the question, that are wrong. One important one is how evolution works, which has now been covered a bit in the answer by user1850479. Another is the relationship between symptoms and transmission. An asymptomatic individual may carry a disease longer, but that doesn't mean they transmit it more than someone symptomatic, even if that person dies.

Comment: You are generalizing my view, fighting a strawman. I said "certain" symptoms (in response to a particular infection/pattern of infection) that make an individual suffer and die, could have evolutionary advantage in stopping an infectious disease that could harm the greater good of the species.

Comment: @ Bryan I really dont get why you guys are saying my understanding of evolution is wrong? So, how are you disproving that it is not possible certain mechanism could develop within the population to stop infectious disease while sacrificing individuals (as a consequence I insist)?

Comment: @BryanKrause, I think you misunderstood the question.  The OP is suggesting that there may be an evolutionary advantage to *displaying* symptoms of severe infectious disease, (presumably because it would alert and thus benefit close relatives of the sick individual).

Comment: The current Covid19 plague may be an example: it appears that *most* carriers in certain slices of the population may be asymptomatic (young people in particular) but able to transmit the virus.

Comment: @Dirigible Please don’t answer questions in comments. There is a specific injunction against it in every comment box on every Stack Exchange site because doing so breaks the model on which Stack Exchange was founded.

Answer (score 2):

> I am curious, is there any known disease/infection that is very severe normally, but ends up having little to no effect on the lives of asymptomatic carriers?

HIV is an obvious example, where so-called "long-term nonprogressors" successfully suppress HIV replication sufficiently that they do not develop AIDS but are unable to clear the infection entirely [1].

> patient suffers greatly and die easily without medical treatment

Since the comments below seem to suggest that HIV does not cause death without medical treatment, I'll point out that this is incorrect.  Over 30 million people have died from HIV infection.

> I am asking this as I am thinking whether this means certain disease symptoms are evolutionarily wired to protect the "greater good"

It does not.  Selection happens on individuals and not whole species, so the greater good is irrelevant.  Asymptomatic infection is a point on the spectrum of possible responses to infection between sterilizing immunity and death. Individuals who are chronically infected mount enough of an immune response to control the infection but not enough to completely clear it.  In the case of HIV, they are typically people who have exceptionally strong immune responses to a normally lethal virus.

### Edit

The comments below suggest a deep misunderstanding of evolution. Since I think these are really the core of your question, I'll address them here.

> If traits really evolve only according to how much an individual reproduce sucessfully, it would be a different world today.

Which individuals reproduce is the sole determinant of which genes are passed down to the next generation.  This is because the genetics of each individual are determined at conception, and cannot be changed.  Hence, reproduction alone determines the traits of the next generation.

To quote wikipedia[2]:

> **Evolution is change in the heritable characteristics of biological populations over successive generations. These characteristics are the expressions of genes that are passed on from parent to offspring during reproduction**. Different characteristics tend to exist within any given population as a result of mutation, genetic recombination and other sources of genetic variation. **Evolution occurs when evolutionary processes such as natural selection (including sexual selection) and genetic drift act on this variation, resulting in certain characteristics becoming more common or rare within a population**

Evolution is the process by which some traits are passed down to the next generation while others are not though the mechanisms of selection (e.g. individuals with harmful traits dying) and genetic drift (e.g. random chance).

> Thank about a hypothetical super fast reproducing bacteria, using up all resources, which means extinction at the end, such traits would not be passed on. In fact some sort of "moderation" mechanism is needed to take care of the "greater good".

This is exactly what happens if you put a lot of fast reproducing bacteria in a closed environment with limited resources.  They will all eventually die.

You seem to be thinking of evolution as something that intelligently looks out for the wellbeing of species.  This is not the case.  Evolution is a random process by which different amounts of reproduction and survival between individuals alters the composition of the succeeding generations. As a random, emergent process it has no goals, no intelligence, and no sense of "good".  Rather, it simply happens as a result of individuals reproducing.  This frequently does lead to extinction, as evidenced by the fact that the vast majority of species no longer exist.

(1) https://academic.oup.com/cid/article/51/2/239/303856
(1) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution

Comment: Thank you for the answer! HIV is an interesting case definitely. However, the severity of AIDS as I understood come from accumulating infections from other pathogens, not the immune response/symptoms to HIV itself which is kind of chronic (I may be wrong). I also disagree with the notion "Selection happens on individuals" makes greater good irrelevant. Even if a stressor act on individuals apparently, it could produce a trait that improves greater good. You can argue the evolution of "dying" is exactly for the greater good. In some diseases, acute symptoms can definitely make you "die faster".

Comment: @ychung Long-term nonprogressors are so called because they do not progress to AIDS.

Comment: @ychung The greater good is irrelevant to selection.  Traits may or may not improve whatever you consider to be "good", but selection does not care about that. Some more reading about what selection is may help you understand that point better.

Comment: My first point is trying to say that HIV/AIDS is not really what I am looking for in the question (thank you for the answer tho). Second point I disagree. Just think about it, traits can definitely be selected in the direction to preserve greater good in the face of large-scale and amplifying stressor (based on population size). Whether "selection does not care about" or not is not important, the consequence is.

Comment: @ychung Edit your question to clarify what you're looking for.  Second point: selection is the process by which individuals either reproduce or do not reproduce. A trait might act on the greater good by accident (see genetic drift), but such traits cannot be selected for. Since you have questions, what selection can and cannot do may be a good topic for a second question.

Comment: Typhoid Mary is a good example I am looking for. 2) By-product/ accident or not etc., it is the result that matters. You are not quite understanding what I am trying to say. Think large-scale, think density-dependent stressor, if traits really evolve only according to how much an individual reproduce sucessfully, it would be a different world today. Thank about a hypothetical super fast reproducing bacteria, using up all resources, which means extinction at the end, such traits would not be passed on. In fact some sort of "moderation" mechanism is needed to take care of the "greater good".

Comment: Similar things can be hypothesized for a hypothetical infectious disease, the denser the infected individuals (which without the "immune reaction" would otherwise die slowly and able to infect many more people), the higher chance the population will go extinct in the long-run.

Comment: I dont think any of the point about evolution disprove what I say (I have never said  evolution as something that intelligently looks out for the wellbeing of species), I said it could happen as a consequence. So, how are you disproving that it is not possible certain mechanism could develop within the population to stop infectious disease while sacrificing individuals (as a consequence I insist)? I dont really get what you are trying to disprove me and saying I misunderstood evolution.

Comment: I meant HIV/AIDS patient die not because of things arise from HIV infection solely, it is complicated from infection of other pathogens. (Which makes it not exactly what I was trying to ask for.) Thanks for the answer but you seem to be misinterpreting me all the time...

Comment: @ychung If you don't want to be misinterpreted, you can edit your post above to reflect your intended question.

Comment: @user1850479, there are many, many examples to contradict your statement that " Selection happens on individuals".  Evolution of altruistic and cooperative behaviors are examples.  Warning colors on toxic butterflies and amphibians are also examples.  Yes, the bright colors of a poison frog deter predators from eating the frog.  But that didn't directly help the first frogs to display those colors: they were eaten and killed by predators who were not repelled by those colors.  *It "trained" predators to avoid that frogs' close relatives.*

Comment: @S.McGrew Selection is one process that can change the traits of an organism, but it is not the only one. Consequently, pointing out the existence of any particular trait doesn't disprove the existence of natural selection.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that anyone is arguing against the existence of natural selection?

Comment: Natural selection is the differential survival and reproduction of individuals due to differences in phenotype.  You listed examples that you believe "contradict" this such as the evolution of cooperative behavior. My point is that other processes can change phenotype besides selection, and so your examples are not necessarily inconsistent with natural selection.

Answer (score 1):

"Yes" is the simple answer to the first part of your question.  HIV, "Typhoid Mary", maybe Covid19, and other examples have been given.

The second part of your question,

> I am asking this as I am thinking whether this means certain disease symptoms are mechanisms resulted from evolution to protect the "greater good", i.e. killing the patient to avoid transmission to another member of the species.

is good, but doesn't have a definite answer as far as I know.  However, your idea is certainly plausible.  Although displaying symptoms (e.g., a rash, cough, odd behavior, or bad odor) will not benefit the individual, it *will* benefit individuals who are repelled by those symptoms.  In cases where individuals who have a tendency to be repelled by the symptoms also have a tendency to display those symptoms (and those tendencies are encoded genetically), close relatives of those individuals have a distinct selective advantage over other individuals in the population who do *not* have a tendency to be repelled.

A lot of literature relating to this idea can be found by searching "evolution of altruism" and "kin selection".

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Displaying horrible symptoms to repel other individuals in the species is definitely one plausible mechanism that can reduce the transmission of pathogens.

Comment: Take note though that the two (displaying symptoms and being repelled by the symptoms) need to become coupled through selective processes, of which kin selection is the most effective.

Comment: Here is an example of the opposite: tuberculosis apparently evolved the ability to enhance its own spread by inducing symptoms: coughing. https://m.medicalxpress.com/news/2020-03-tuberculosis-bacteria-trigger.html

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said symptoms killing the patient (which in itself constitute a severe warning to other members of the species) is a more "direct" mechanism to stop transmission.

Comment: That's not quite what I meant.  It can be a co-evolutionary process.  A microbe can evolve to cause symptoms that help spread it; a species can evolve to respond to a microbe by displaying scary symptoms;  it's even possible for a species to respond to the microbe by suppressing the symptoms that help the microbe spread.

Comment: Yes, I know what you are saying. There are many different possibilities indeed.  For all the different immune response-pathogen combinations possible, it is the end result of a co-evolutionary arm race with some trickery and mimicry mixed within.

Comment: But I tilt it to humans as the main subject of evolution here because I think early humans evolve mainly by being killed and survival given that prehistoric humans live in tribes or isolated populations, only the tribe that has the right traits perpetuate. Whereas virus evolution has a whole lot of other mechanisms (like its inherent high mutation), many cases a virus may just be an opportunist capitalizes on a human trait when it hasnt even co-evolved with humans that long. (that's why I insist it is the pattern of infection, not the actual virus that matters)

Comment: It's plausible.  You should put together a mathematical model (that's "falsifiable") and see how well it fits.  The model should allow for other answers too, and compare how well they fot relative to each other.  And, just to complicate things, *all* of the varoius evolutionary processes are probably going on simultaneously!

Comment: Well I can only hope I have the required expertise :( Unfortunately, I do biogeochemical modeling instead. Maybe someday an evolutionary biologist will stumble upon this thread :)

Comment: It might be a fun and educational exercise for you anyway, even though you don't have experience in this field.  Important contributions to a field are often made by smart people who come in from another field with a fresh perspective.